# How an ArrayList<Integer> stores 'null' value in the below program?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, executorservice

```
public class SampleExecutorService {
    private int count = 0;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    private void increment() {
        count++;
        numbers.add(count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        SampleExecutorService obj = new SampleExecutorService();
        Runnable task = obj::increment;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            executorService.submit(task);

        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.numbers.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.numbers.size());
    }   
}
```

I just increment the count and add that value to the array list. Sometimes it stores expected values, but sometimes not( the `ArrayList<Integer>` contains 'null' values). kindly help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Javadoc of `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

You're adding elements from multiple threads, but not synchronizing it externally. As such, you are liable to see undefined behavior in the list - for example, `null` elements when you never actually add null.

You can fix this trivially by using the hint in the Javadoc:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

(Note that you may see other "unexpected" behavior still, for example the same number added twice, because `count` isn't being incremented atomically; or elements not in the correct order in the list)

Comment: @Andy Turner Could you please explain how the elements can end up in incorrect order or how an element can be added twice if you are using a synchronized List?

Comment: This can happen if you have 2 executions in 2 separate threads that are both at the same line of code (after increment before adding). This could cause the same number to be added twice to the array.

Comment: @alexrolea Incorrect order: Thread A gets 1, increments. Thread B gets 2, increments. Thread B adds 2 to list. Thread A adds 1 to list.

Comment: @alexrolea Same number added twice: Thread A gets 1, increments but value is not pushed down to main memory. Thread B gets 1, increments but value is not pushed down to main memory. Both add 1 to list.

Comment: @alexrolea the point is that the getting and incrementing of `counter` is not atomic, nor guaranteed to be visible.

Comment: @Gerben Jongerius The implementation for `add` from `SynchronizedCollection` is `public boolean add(E e) {synchronized (mutex) {return c.add(e);}}`. I think threads would wait after one another before entering the `c.add(e)` method (so they can't both at the same line of code of increment before adding).

Comment: @alexrolea the add to the list is synchronized; [getting and incrementing] is not synchronized, nor is [getting, incrementing and adding to the list] synchronized as a whole.

Comment: @AndyTurner If you are using the synchronized wrapper, all relevant methods are synchronized, so there is no way two threads could corrupt your data (since threads wait one after the other before entering the CS). Even if a thread would swap out in the middle of the CS, it would go to sleep holding the lock and therefore not allowing other threads to enter the CS. This is why synchronized collections inherit bad performance and we need concurrent structures. Am I getting anything wrong here?

Comment: What I mean is, although  [getting and incrementing] is not synchronized, there is no way two threads can get there at the same time since that code block itself is synchronized by `synchronized (mutex) {return c.add(e);}` from `SynchronizedCollection`, since it is somewhere inside the `add(e)` method.

Comment: "since that code block itself is synchronized" The getting and incrementing does not happen in a synchronized block. Nor is the value of `counter` read in a synchronized way when passing it to the `add` method. Synchronization only happens once the method has been invoked, which necessarily happens after evaluating the parameters.

Comment: @Andy Turner `sync = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());`. When you invoke `sync.add(e)`, this is what happens. The `add` method from `SynchronizedList` is invoked, which locks the collection. From this point on the collection is locked until the current thread finishes the insertion. The `add` from `SynchronizedList` invokes the `add` from `ArrayList`. Note you are in synchronized context. The `add` from `ArrayList` does the insertion via `elementData[index] = element;size++;`, still in synchronized context from the initial `sync.add(e)`.

Comment: @Andy Turner Since synchronized collections are implemented via monitors https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: @alexrolea I think we all agree that the method add of the synchronized collection would not cause the issue. What both I and Andy are trying to get across is that the method increment in the SampleExecutorService is not synchronized. So if multiple threads execute that method then there is a possibility that they both execute the add method at the same time with the same incremental count.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius My initial comment "Could you please explain how the elements can end up in incorrect order or how an element can be added twice **if you are using a synchronized List**?". About what `SampleExecutorService` are you talking about?

Comment: What I am trying to get across is that this `"Note that you may see other "unexpected" behavior still, for example the same number added twice, because count isn't being incremented atomically; or elements not in the correct order in the list"` is not correct.

Comment: @alexrolea [it is demonstrably correct](https://ideone.com/VLs5ZA). The out-of-orderness happens reliably; you may need to run it a few times to see that it doesn't always add 2M distinct elements. (I get it much more reliably on my workstation than ideone).

Comment: @AndyTurner The culprit for that is not the synchronized list but what you are passing to the add method of the synchronized list. https://ideone.com/oFMdji

Comment: @alexrolea .... which is what I have been saying all along, especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702589/how-an-arraylistinteger-stores-null-value-in-the-below-program/52702633?noredirect=1#comment92333554_52702633). BTW, your code will still suffer from the issue of things not always being added in ascending order.